# If readable.pipe() returns a Writable, how can we chain pipes?

Tags: node.js

The Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) says, that `readable.pipe(destination[, options])`  'returns a reference to the destination stream making it possible to set
up chains of piped streams'.

The [documentation for stream.Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) doesn't mention the method `pipe`, so it seems the method is not available.

But how should it be possible to call the `pipe`-method on the returned `Writeable` if the method is not available on it?

Example:

```
    |-> returns a Writable
    |
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
            |
            |-> How is the chained pipe available here?
```

Am I missing the point or is the documentation missing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you continue to scroll down that same page, you will find the documentation for [Duplex and Transform Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams). Both `stream.Duplex` and `stream.Transform` implement both the `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable` interfaces. You can use these to chain `.pipe` calls. In fact, they exist for this exact purpose

A common example is reading, gzipping and writing a file...

```
const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
const fs = require('fs');
const inp = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
const out = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz');

inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

In this example, `zlib.createGzip()` returns a `Transform` stream. You can create your own custom transforms by subclassing `stream.Transform`

Comment: Yes, I read it. But that means `readable.pipe()` would actually not just return a `stream.Writable`.

Comment: The part of the documentation you are referencing is just one example. A few lines below that, they show another example of piping and clearly state "The readable.pipe() method returns a reference to the destination stream making it possible to set up chains of piped streams". I agree the wording is a bit tricky, but what is returned by a `pipe` depends on what you are piping to. The documentation is not  wrong though, because a Duplex or Transform stream is technically a Writable stream. It is just also a Readable stream

Comment: In other words, what is returned by `.pipe` must be a `Writable`. However, it can also be both `Readable` and `Writable` which allows chaining. If they didn't have the requirement that it be a `Writable`, you'd have a situation where you could not write the result of a pipe and had to chain it, which would not be very composable